# jsPDF pdf file name = Unknown.pdf on ios

Tags: pdf, jspdf

I have a problem in jsPDF with the name of the file:

I use this code:

```
let text = doc.splitTextToSize(JSON.stringify(myText), 180);
        doc.setProperties({
          title: 'My Title',
          subject: 'Something...',
          author: 'Me',
        })
        doc.text(text, 20, 20)
        doc.save('my_file.pdf');
```

when I try to save on android it goes fine but, when I try to save on iOS devices the name of the file is "Unknown.pdf".

How can I change that name?
I also tried doc.output('save', 'filename.pdf'); but without results.

Thank you!